# tcp server failing after first loop

Tags: c#, c, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

As above really, I'm trying to create a tcp linux server in c to accept data, perform some processing then send it back.

The code I'm trying to use on the client side to send the data and then read it back:

```
        TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
        tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.0.14", 1235);
        NetworkStream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            _signal.WaitOne();
            Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = null;
            while (_queue.TryDequeue(out frame))
            {
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    resizedBMPFrame = frame.Resize(0.5, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR).ToBitmap();
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        resizedBMPFrame.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                        byte[] byteFrame = ms.ToArray();
                        l = byteFrame.Length;
                        byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(l.ToString());
                        stm.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        stm.Write(byteFrame, 0, byteFrame.Length);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Reading = false;
                }              
            int i;
            Bitmap receivedBMPFrame;
            byte[] receivedFramesize = new byte[4];
            int j = stm.Read(receivedFramesize, 0, receivedFramesize.Length);
            int receivedFramesizeint = BitConverter.ToInt32(receivedFramesize, 0);
            byte[] receivedFrame = new byte[receivedFramesizeint];
            j = stm.Read(receivedFrame, 0, receivedFrame.Length);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(receivedFrame))
            {
                receivedBMPFrame = new Bitmap(ms);
                if (receivedBMPFrame != null)
                {
                    outputVideoPlayer.Image = receivedBMPFrame;
                }
                else
                {
                    Reading = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stm.Close();
    tcpclnt.Close();
```

So the idea is it waits for the display thread to send the current frame it's displaying using a concurrentqueue, it then takes it, and makes it a quarter of the size, converts it to a byte array and then sends its length and then it itself over the tcp socket.

In theory the server gets it, performs some processing then sends it back, so it reads the length of it then the new frame itself.

The server code is below:

```
while (1)
{
    int incomingframesize;

    int n;
    n = read(conn_desc, framesizebuff, 6);
    if ( n > 0)
    {       
        printf("Length of incoming frame is %s\n", framesizebuff);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed receiving length\n");
        return -1;
    }
    char framebuff[atoi(framesizebuff)];

    n = read(conn_desc, framebuff, atoi(framesizebuff));
    if ( n > 0)
    {

        printf("Received frame\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed receiving frame\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Ready to write\n");

    int k = sizeof(framebuff);
    n = write(conn_desc, &k, sizeof(int));
    if (n <0)
    {
        printf("ERROR writing to socket\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Return frame size is %d\n", k);
    }

    n = write(conn_desc, &framebuff, sizeof(char)*k);
    if (n <0)
    {
        printf("ERROR writing to socket\n");
    }
    frameno++;
    printf("Frames sent: %d\n", frameno);
}
```

So it reads the length, then the actual frame, which seems to work, and at the moment then just sends it straight back without doing any processing. However it only works for one loop seemingly, if I step through the client code line by line the server code runs through once, but on the 2nd read by the client, receiving the frame from the server, the server then runs the two reads of the loop straight away, without waiting for another write. Failing on the 2nd having seemingly read in nothing as it outputs:

```
Length of incoming frame is
Failed receiving frame
```

With no number, which to me makes sense as I haven't sent another write with the length of the next frame. I'm just wondering what I'm missing/why it's acting like this? As on the first loop it waits until the write commands from the client. I'm wondering if it means there is left over data in the write stream, so when it goes back to the top it immediately reads it again? Although it then doesn't print any form of number which to me implies there's nothing there...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT/UPDATE:
Changed the read/write sections on the server to do a single byte at a time like this:

```
while (ntotal != incomingframesize)
    {
    n = read(conn_desc, &framebuff[ntotal], sizeof(char));
    ntotal = ntotal + n;

while (i < k)
    {
    m = write(conn_desc, &framebuff[i], sizeof(char));
```

Which seems to have solved the problems I was having and now the correct data is being transferred :)

Comment: When you put a debugger breakpoint on the 'n = read(conn_desc, framesizebuff, 6);' line, and hit this the second time to examine 'framebuff', did it contain a valid null-terminated string representing a data length?

Answer (score 0):

When the client writes the frame size it uses the length of some object, but when the server reads it always tries to read 6 characters. You need to use a fixed length for the frame size!

When reading, you cannot assume that you get as many bytes as you ask for. The return value, if >0, is the number of bytes actually read. If you get less than you asked for, you need to keep reading until you have received the number of bytes you expect.

First read until you've got 6 bytes (frame size).

Next read until you've got the number of bytes indicated by the frame size.

Make sure you use the same number of bytes for the frame size in all places.

**Edit:**

I also noted a bug in the call to `write` in the server:

```
n = write(conn_desc, &framebuff, sizeof(char)*k);
```

`framebuff` is a pointer to the data, so you probably mean:

```
n = write(conn_desc, &framebuff[0], k);
```

Comment: I've currently set it to 6 as I know the value being sent is 179766, and stepping through my client code I can see buf.Length is 6. But in general you're saying I need to enclose my read statements in loops to make sure I'm actually reading the correct amount? I guess I misunderstood the read command, I thought it would read until I got that many bytes?


Edit: Just checked something, n equals 5840 in the 2nd read statement on the server, which obviously isn't what I want, but I don't understand why?

Comment: @GeorgeStorm look, you have a misbehaving system with a client and server.  Which end is faulty?  Maybe both?   Cut the problem in half - use Wireshark to find out what is REALLY being sent to what.

Comment: Well, I took Klas's advice and implemented a loop making sure I'm reading in the correct number of bytes (which I clearly wasn't beforehand!) which seems to work fine, however when sending the data back, the array isn't the same as the one I sent to the server. The receivedFrame array is just full of 0s, so I'm guessing the problem is on the server end, I'll look into using wireshark to try and see what data is being sent.

Comment: You receive n bytes, but send back k :(

Comment: I've edited my code so my original read on the server is checking n = 6, and I've got a while loop until it's read in the correct amount of data (ntotal). I've tried changing k to ntotal and the same data gets sent. Just a bunch of 0s, checked with wireshark as well, the correct data is being sent by the client, but not back from the server :/

Comment: Found the reason the data gets corrupted. See edit in my answer.

Comment: I'm wanting to send the entire array of data, your edit will just send the first entry I think? I tried having just framebuff without the & and it still sent 0s.
Are you suggesting I put that command in a while loop, cycling through the entire array sending a single byte at a time?

Comment: Well, after changing several things I thought of trying to send and receive a single byte at a time, looping through until reaching the appropriate number of bytes. So I tried it, and it works! Still not really sure what was going wrong before, I think it was in fact the read command on the server, but now that I'm reading a single byte into &framebuff[ntotal] each time until ntotal=incomingframesize and then writing one byte at a time using a similar loop the correct data seems to be transferred. Now I'm getting some threading issues (I think) but that's for another question :P)

Comment: You should try to read/write the remaining number of bytes and count forward the actual number of bytes sent/received until you are done.